# Comparing with NULL values

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `mycompare` (
  `name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `mname` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `mycompare` VALUES('amar', 'ajay', 'shankar', NULL);
INSERT INTO `mycompare` VALUES('akbar', 'bhai', 'aslam', 'akbar');
INSERT INTO `mycompare` VALUES('anthony', 'john', 'Jim', 'Ken');
_____

SELECT * FROM mycompare WHERE (name = fname OR name = mname OR name = lname)
akbar   bhai    aslam   akbar

select * from mycompare where !(name = fname OR name = mname OR name = lname)
anthony john    Jim Ken
```

In the second select above, I expect the "amar" record as well because that name does not match with First, second or last name.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Any comparison with `NULL` yields `NULL`. To overcome this, there are three operators you can use:

- `x IS NULL` - determines whether left hand expression is `NULL`,
- `x IS NOT NULL` - like above, but the opposite,
- `x <=> y` - compares both operands for equality in a safe manner, i.e. `NULL` is seen as a normal value.

For your code, you might want to consider using the third option and go with the null safe comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM mycompare 
WHERE NOT(name <=> fname OR name <=> mname OR name <=> lname)
```

Comment: More info: [MySQL Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 6):

You [cannot use relational operators with `NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html). The only operators that work with `NULL` are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I was writing update triggers and wanted to execute portion of code only when two values **different**. Using [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) and [`XOR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor) came in handy:

```sql
SELECT 1!=1;                          -- 0
SELECT 1!=2;                          -- 1
SELECT 1!=NULL;                       -- NULL
SELECT NULL!=NULL;                    -- NULL
SELECT NULL IS NULL XOR 1 IS NULL;    -- 1
SELECT NULL IS NULL XOR NULL IS NULL; -- 0
SELECT 1 IS NULL XOR 1 IS NULL;       -- 0
```

So I've ended up using:

```sql
IF (OLD.col != NEW.col) OR ((OLD.col IS NULL) XOR ( NEW.col IS NULL)) THEN ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` values are omitted automatically if you do a value comparison (because `NULL` isn't a value). Your `where` clause basically means: Compare the values of the mentioned fields, *if they have a value*—otherwise false.

You'd have to include a separate check for `NULL` if you want those rows, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get away with something like the following (assuming that mapping NULL to '' is not a problem):

```
SELECT * FROM mycompare 
WHERE (ifnull(name,'') = ifnull(fname,'') 
       OR ifnull(name,'') = ifnull(mname,'') 
       OR ifnull(name,'') = ifnull(lname,''));

select * from mycompare 
where !(ifnull(name,'') = ifnull(fname,'') 
        OR ifnull(name,'') = ifnull(mname,'')  
        OR ifnull(name,'') = ifnull(lname,''));
```