# selecting a filtered multiple fields where value is "null"

Tags: mysql, sql

my MYSQL -database is something like this ,

```
id    field_1   field_2    field_3   field_4  - - - - - - - - -  field_120
1     hello     hi         null       again                       null              
2     stack     bad        good       null                        null
"     bye       null       null       null                        null
```

this table is general description,

id is auto increment and all fields are same datatype , i have around 1000's rows in this table,

i would like to verify fields(field_1 ,field_2, .... ) which are not used (NULL) for all customers,

i tried using NULLIF statements but it did not work out, Can anyone please help,

Comment: `WHERE field_1 IS NULL`

Comment: So what.. what? You're trying to get all the fields that have `NULL` in? Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing with NULL values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393076/comparing-with-null-values)

Comment: You should also know that this is bad practise. Use a `JOIN` and have all the fields in a different table `(id, field_id, value)`. `id` would be your `id` in your current table. `field_id` would be 1-120. `value` would be the value (helo, hi, `NULL` etc).

Comment: indirectly i want to know which fields are empty for all id's  , not just one field verification

Comment: @ h2o0 , actually i am limited in this case , i must use all fields as colomns ,i know what you mean

Comment: If you split it up into multiple tables it's as simple as `SELECT t.id, f.field_id FROM table t INNER JOIN fields f ON f.id = t.id WHERE f.value IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(`field_1` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as `field_1_has_non_null`,
    SUM(IF(`field_2` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as `field_2_has_non_null`,
    SUM(IF(`field_3` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as `field_3_has_non_null`,
    ...
    SUM(IF(`field_118` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as `field_118_has_non_null`,
    SUM(IF(`field_119` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as `field_119_has_non_null`,
    SUM(IF(`field_120` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) as `field_120_has_non_null`,
FROM
    `table`
```

If `field_1_has_non_null` is more than 0, then a non-NULL value was found in `field1`.
If `field_2_has_non_null` is more than 0, then a non-NULL value was found in `field2`.

etc.