# mysql col != 1 returning 0 resultset if col is nullable

Tags: mysql

```
`type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
```

DATA SET

id name type 
1   abc   1 
2   bcd   NULL 
3   efg   NULL

QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type!=1;
```

The query returns 0 result set

Problem explanation or solution requested.
No alternates please.

Comment: DId you try <> instead of != like type<>1

Comment: @JarachanthanRatnakumar that's not the problem here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a special case for `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IS NULL OR type !=1;
```

Comment: != 1 is valid SQL syntax?

Comment: I think that (!=) is only applicable to certain versions of SQL?

Comment: @Gosu, one of them being MySQL

Comment: If you are feeling clever, `WHERE type IS NOT TRUE` will also match only 0 and NULL.  Only one of those is false (NULL is not false), but both are indeed `NOT TRUE`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I'm feeling clever, but that's not what OP asked for.

Comment: Not explicitly, you're correct.  Given the example data, it looks like 1 and NULL are the possible values.  I may have assumed incorrectly.  In any event, my comment wasn't intended to suggest that this was somehow a better solution.  `WHERE NOT (type <=> 1)` would also have worked, and is more precise to the point of the actual question. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IS NULL;
```

if you are looking for those rows where the **type** has the value "NULL"

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp), it says:

> NULL values are treated differently from other values.
>   It is not possible to compare NULL and 0; they are not equivalent.

Basically, you should be using **`xxx IS NULL`** or **`xxx IS NOT NULL`**.

Comment: That's not what OP needs.

Comment: @shmosel Why not? He's trying to use type != 1 which is wrong?

Comment: @Gosu shmosel is right .
It's not what i need.
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type <> 1;
won't even work for me

Answer (score 1):

NULL != 1 returns null and it is not equal to true.

Try running `SELECT type , type != 1 as flag FROM table`

You will get 0 as flag where `type` = 1. And NULL as flag where `TYPE` = NULL

You may change the query as

```
select * from table where coalesce(type, 0) != 1
```

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393076/comparing-with-null-values)