# PHP is not getting data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have the next problem:

My code is this one:

```
$id=$_SESSION["id"];
$query="select id_period from periods where id_group=$id and end=NULL";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
$insert=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into periods(id_group) values($id)");
}

while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
   $period=$row['id_period'];
}

$query="insert into times(id_period,id_group) values($period,$id)";
echo $query;
$insert=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

This code should search if exists a 'period' with field 'end'=NULL. If not, then insert a new one. That works fine. However, the next part doesn't working. The insert into 'times' query needs the id_period, given by the var $period, but the WHILE never runs.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393076/comparing-with-null-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find problem in below while code

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   $period=$row['id_period'];
}
```

In this for fetching data from result set you have use mysqli_fetch_row as per php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php  mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an enumerated array.

If you are interested in getting data using name as an index then please use 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php it mysqli_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row as an associative array.

Hopes it helps you.

Comment: Working! I had already trying to use fetch_assoc, but surely I had another problem in that moment, so I discarded that. Thank you a lot!